# How to reduce the costs of an sql select with order by?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm executing lots of sql selects as follows. Imagine we have a database with flights, where each flight might have an outbound and inbound airport of course, a departure date, a number of stops between origin and destination (on long flights), and of course  price.

I now want to select a specific route, and select the one with the lowest count of stops, and of course the bestprice among them.

```
CREATE TABLE flights(
    id integer
    outbound character varying,
    inbound character varying,
    date timestamp,
    stops integer
    price numeric
);
CREATE INDEX my_idx ON flights (outbound, inbound, date, stops, price);

select * from flights where outbound = 'SFO' and inbound = 'SYD' and date = '2015-10-10' and stops < 2 order by stops asc, price asc.
```

Problem: the costs using `explain-analyze` are quite high:

```
Sort  (cost=9.78..9.79 rows=1 width=129) (actual time=0.055..0.055 rows=4 loops=1)
  Sort Key: stops, price
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
  ->  Index Scan using my_idx  (cost=0.42..9.77 rows=1 width=129) (actual time=0.039..0.041 rows=4 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((date = '2015-10-10'::date) AND ((outbound)::text = 'SFO'::text) AND (stops < 2) AND ((inbound)::text = 'SYD'::text))
Total runtime: 0.079 ms
```

If I just sort by price without stops, the costs are ok (0.42). But sorting by stops somehow increases the costs siginificant.

How can I reduce the costs?

`postgresql 9.3.2`

Comment: You version of Postgres is crucial (and should always be in the question).

Comment: `postgresql 9.3.2` updated above

Comment: Err... The estimated cost is actually tiny. `0.42..9.77` -> `9.78..9.79`. What's costly in there is locating the rows. Are you sure you should be worrying about the cost of sorting *four* rows? :-)

Comment: Do you actually need *all* columns (`SELECT *`) or can you reduce that set?

Comment: I don't know, but I thought the sorting costs are quite high and maybe I *could* reduce them somehow.

Comment: yes usually I need all columns on the select.

Comment: Well, actually they're not. They costs involved are *tiny*. Like `0.01..0.02` tiny, if you strip out the previous start-up and execution cost estimates. Also look at the actual times involved.

Comment: Your numbers are contradicting. `Total runtime: 0.079 ms`, while the supposedly faster query has `0.42`? Can you clarify that?

Comment: How can I know if actually the costs are stated as `cost=9.78..9.79`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: As I read the question, the 0.42 OP mentioned correspond to the first part of the `0.42..9.77` estimated cost.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I did not modify any timings, just copy-paste it from pgadmin.

Comment: Your query runs for 0.079 milliseconds (that's 0.000079 seconds). How much faster do you need this to get? Plus a total cost of 9.79 is really, really small. Why do you focus on an arbitrary "cost" value if there is no performance problem in the first place.

Comment: OK I see I'm probably overestimating my concerns about the sorting costs here.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: That's not conclusive. 0.42 refers to an alternate query, the plan of which is not there.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: It might be my misunderstanding, but as I read the question, OP doesn't seem to be realizing that the figures for the sort step are the *total cumulative* costs in the plan upon entering and exiting that step, rather than the *specific* costs related to that individual step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the given numbers, your alternate query (*"If I just sort by price without stops"*) is actually **slower**, and you misread the numbers. `0.079 ms` vs. `0.42` (?).

That also makes sense, because your first query matches the sort order of the index perfectly.

**You already have the perfect index**. The suggestion to remove `price` is unfounded. The additional column removes the cost for the sort step: `time=0.055..0.055` as you can see in the plan.

Either way, it should hardly matter at all. As soon as you have reduced the number of rows retrieved to a *small* number (with predicates on the leading columns of the index), the rest is cheap either way.

To get more interesting results, don't test with `stops < 2` (which only leaves 0 and 1 stops), try with a bigger number to see any (probably small) difference.

Actually, since almost all columns are in the index already, I would try and add the one missing column `id`, too - if you can get [**index-only scans**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) out of this (Postgres 9.2+, read the Postgres Wiki at the linked page):

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx ON flights (outbound, inbound, date, stops, price, id);
```

```
SELECT id, outbound, inbound, date, stops, price
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select * 
from flights
where outbound = 'SFO' and inbound = 'SYD' and date = '2015-10-10' and stops < 2
order by stops asc, price asc.
```

The optimal index is:  `flights(outbound, inbound, date, stops)`.  This applies to the `where` clause.  I don't know if there is a way to eliminate the `order by`, given the `where` but the sort should not be a big deal unless there are thousands of flights on that day.

Comment: Maybe I even don't need the index in stops here? The difference without stops indexed is `0.006ms`. Whould you think in this case having an index of 3 instead of 4 columns is more of a benefit then?

Comment: @membersound . . . `stops` probably has a minimal impact, depending on the number of routines that have more than one stop.  But I would include it, because an additional column in an index is not a whole lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The costs are an arbitrary figure.

Moreover, the figures for the sort step are the *total cumulative* costs in the plan upon entering and exiting that step, rather than the *specific* costs related to that individual step.

Your query is fine doing a quick sort. It's only four rows, and it completes the entire query in 0.079 ms.